# How can I restore my device with simply ipsw file and iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod, restore, ipsw

I want to restore my iPod touch 4 gen. using a previously downloaded `.ipsw` file from the web instead of iTunes trying to download it again. I have tried putting the `.ipsw` file in the `~/Library/iTunes/iPod Software Updates/` folder but it still downloads another one.

By the way, my iPod is stuck in recovery mode and I cannot cannot get it out of it except restoring the iPod. What should I do?

Answer (score 32):

Option-click the Restore button in iTunes and a standard file-selection dialog comes up allowing you to find your .ipsw file.

Answer (score 9):

Shift-click the Restore button in iTunes for windows user

Comment: As of iTunes 12, the button is labeled "Restore iPhone..."

Answer (score 1):

As of macOS Catalina, this is done directly in Finder. When your phone is connected to the computer, it shows up in the Finder sidebar under the "Locations" section. (If you don't see it, make sure it is checked under Finder settings, which you can get to with command-comma.)

Under this tab, option-click the "Restore" button and choose the `.ipsw` file.