# Problems upgrading my iphone from iOS6 to iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone

I have problems when I attempt to upgrade my iPhone from iOS6 to iOS7. I went so many time to general and software update but it will run checking for hours and nothing and I need to have iOS 7 or up.

Comment: Which iPhone did you try to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You can check apple signing status and download the correct firmware and software from [ipsw rocks](http://www.ipsw.rocks) if you need any help then contact me via this site.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has stopped signing iOS 7 for all except legacy products [essentially iPhone 4]
If your device is capable, your only choice now is to go to iOS 8, unless you wanted to risk jailbreaking it.

[Source [IPSW Downloads](https://ipsw.me)]

That link is also good for downloading the specific ipsw file for that device, allowing you to manually initiate the update from iTunes - covered by [How can I restore my device with simply ipsw file and iTunes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111536/how-can-i-restore-my-device-with-simply-ipsw-file-and-itunes)